# Why do we need to set the recipient explicitly for IMessenger.Subscribe()?

Tags: mvvm-light

Here is the singature of the `Register` method:

```
IMessanger.Register<TMsg>(object recipient, Action<TMsg> action);
```

Why do we need the recipient if action holds the reference in its Target property?
When the given action does not use instance members of the class where it was defined then Target is null.
But this happens quite rarely. I mean that it is not a very common way we use event handlers.

I'd like to understand why there is no additonal `Register` method signature with no  recipient parameter? Am I missing something important?

```
IMessanger.Register<TMsg>(Action<TMsg> action);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually register a recipient for a specific message from anywhere in your application, not just from the class that is the recipient. For example, consider the following scenario:

```
public class ClassA : ViewModelBase
{
    public ClassA()
    {
         Messenger.Default.Register<SomeMessage>(this, SomeAction);
         Messenger.Default.Register<SomeMessage>(ViewModelLocator.ClassB, SomeAction);
    }

    private void SomeAction(SomeMessage msg)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public class ClassB : ViewModelBase
{
    public ClassB()
    {

    }
}
```

In the case of the second `Registor` method call, the Target property of the Action will NOT be the same as the recipient parameter. Therefore, to be consistent, it was most likely safer to always require a recipient parameter.

Of course, you are correct that this scenario is probably less common than the scenario where you simply pass `this` as the recipient. So in that case, if typing `this` becomes to burdensome for you then you could always define your own `Register` extension method which simply passes the Target property along to the actual `Register` method:

```
public static class MessengerHelper
{
    public static void Register<TMessage>(this IMessenger messenger, Action<TMessage> action)
    {
        messenger.Register<TMessage>(action.Target, action);
    }
}
```

You can then register for messages like this:

```
public class ClassA : ViewModelBase
{
    public ClassA()
    {
         Messenger.Default.Register<SomeMessage>(SomeAction);
    }

    private void SomeAction(SomeMessage msg)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: But how recipient value is used? Is not just Action enough to react on bound message? Or TDaver  already said about is as a facility to unregister all handlers with single call.

Comment: How is the recipient value used? The various Message classes have a `Target` property which corresponds to a specific recipient. So if you set the `Target` property on the Message before sending it then only that object will receive the Message. Therefore, the messaging system needs you to specify the recipient when calling the `Register` method so that the right messages get to the right recipient. Would you expect to receive your mail if you didn't give the carrier your name when registering for postal service?

Comment: The answer TDaver provided only explains a convenience provided by the Messenger class because your messages are already registered with a recipient. However, it does not explain the purpose of the recipient in the first place. That purpose is simply for locating the correct object when a Message's Target property is set.

Answer (score 0):

It is done so you can say `Messenger.UnregisterRecepient(recepient);` which then unsubscribes every action registered to this receiver.

Comment: I think the OP meant something to the affect of "Why doesn't the `Register` method assume the recipient based on the Target property of the Action parameter?"